# How does this work in C++ and any rough equiavalnce of this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++

I am currently working on an encryption/decryption program written in C++. There is a snippet in the code which I have not understood. I have been trying to convert entire source into JavaScript.

I have two questions:

1. How does this code work? I am very new to C++ programming.
2. Any rough equivalence of this in JavaScript?

```
uint32_t char_to_int(char c){
  if(c >='0' && c<='9')
    return c -'0'; 
  else 
    return c - 'a' + 10; 
}
```

Comment: The javascript equivalent would be roughly the same... What exactly don't you understand in this line of code?

Comment: What I have understood is this code converts the character into integer. If it's 0 then it 0 , if it's 1 then 1 .. However if it's an 'a' then it outputs 10 and so on. When trying to implement the same code in JS it says NaN.

Comment: Also this code looks a bit unsafe, because when `c < ('a' - 10)` then you'll get a integer underflow.

Comment: So you understood what the function does, but not _why_ it is doing so ;) And you're not to blame, it is undocummented and poorly named. What if the function was instead `hex_digit_to_integer(char c)`?

Comment: Pretty much yes.  How does that  minus(-) operator work ? Can we do the same thing with JS? When i tried to do it always throws NaN.

Comment: @PhoneixRaidar see the spec of js' operator minus (`-`): https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers

Answer (score 5):

> 1) How does this code work?
>
> ```
> uint32_t char_to_int(char c){
>   if(c >='0' && c<='9')
>     return c -'0';
>   else
>     return c - 'a' + 10;
>  }
> ```

that just return the integer value 0 .. 15 from an hexadecimal digit '0' .. '9' or 'a' .. 'f'

- if *c* is the character '3' the first test is true so it returns '3' - '0' = 3
- if *c* is the character 'b' the test is false and the code returns 'b' - 'a' + 10 = 11

> 2) Any rough equivalence of this in JavaScript?

in javascript just use  `parseInt(hexString, 16);`

---

If I complete the given code  to be able to use it :

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned uint32_t;
```

> ```
> uint32_t char_to_int(char c) {
>   if(c >='0' && c<='9')
>     return c -'0';
>   else
>     return c - 'a' + 10;
>  }
> ```

```
int main()
{
  for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c)
    std::cout << c << " -> " << char_to_int(c) << std::endl;

  for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'f'; ++c)
    std::cout << c << " -> " << char_to_int(c) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The execution is :

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
5 -> 5
6 -> 6
7 -> 7
8 -> 8
9 -> 9
a -> 10
b -> 11
c -> 12
d -> 13
e -> 14
f -> 15
```

Comment: What happens if `c = 'A'` :)?

Comment: @Neijwiert the code only manages the lower characters from 'a', so with 'A' the value will be 'A' - 'a' + 10 = -22

Comment: I got that but how do we convert it into JS?

Comment: I edited my answer, just use parseInt for the conversion

Comment: @bruno I think you mean `4294967274`, not `-22`.

Comment: parseInt(hexString,16) does work only for values in this range [0-9a-f]

Comment: @PhoneixRaidar like the C(++) code you given, so it is your answer

Comment: `code` function char_to_int(c){
  if(c >='0' && c<='9'){
    return c -'0'; 
  } else {
    return c - 'a' + 10; 
  }
}

char_to_int('a') returns NaN . I wanted it to return 10 also the as the above code does this should work for all the alphabets and other values as well

Comment: @PhoneixRaidar no, the function return 10 for 'a',I don't know how you did the transformation to a float but you did wrong ;-)

Comment: I have tried it in console . It does not. Could you please show case me it somewhere?

Comment: @PhoneixRaidar look again at my answer

Comment: This answer is incomplete even in C and C++.   It does not ONLY convert to hex.    It is actually closer to the conversion done done by `strtoul()`, except that it acts on a single character, not a string.   `strtoul()` can convert values for bases up to `36`, not just hex.   `strtoul()` also handles uppercase letters sensibly, which the OPs code does not  - and also works on systems with character sets with a non-contiguous set of lower-case letters.

Comment: @Peter " It does not ONLY convert to hex" it does not convert to hex at all. And I answer to the 2 questions, why are you saying the answer is incomplet ?. I do not understand you

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> uint32_t char_to_int(char c){
>   if(c >='0' && c<='9')
>       return c -'0'; 
>   else 
>       return c - 'a' + 10; 
>   }
> ```

This function converts digits (`'0'` to `'9'`), to their numeric equivalent   i.e.   `'0'` is converted to `0`, `'1'` is converted to `1`, .... `'9'` is converted to `9`.

The  `c - 'a' + 10`, converts lower case letters to a numeric equivalent viz `'a'` becomes `10`, `'b'` becomes `11`, ..... `'z'` becomes `35`.    However, this ONLY works if the implementation (i.e. compiler) uses a character set with a contiguous set of lower-case letters (like ASCII).   There are real-world character sets that do not have a contiguous set of lower-case letters though.

The problem is that conversion is also done for all characters, other than digits, and the result is then probably meaningless.   For example, it will not correctly handle uppercase letters (if one expects uppercase letters to be converted to the same as their lowercase equivalents).

The function operates on one character at a time.   It attempts to do the same thing as the standard function `strtoul()` except, except that `strtoul()` (1) works on a string (not a single character), (2) works correctly for both upper and lower case letters, (3) will work correctly regardless of what character set the implementation supports, and (4) does error checking (e.g. returning zero if an invalid character is detected).     `strtoul()` is not limited to hex conversion - it works up to base `35`.

As to an equivalent in JavaScript - essentially the same code will probably work, but with flaws similar to those in the C/C++ version.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `char` is an integral type like `int`. A character literal, like `'a'` or `'0'`, is of an integral type too, and not a string like in JavaScript.

In JavaScript, you would get such an integral value (character code) by using `s.charCodeAt(0)` to your one-character string `s`. For longer strings, it will return the character code of the first character.

The table of codes for the base character set for the predominantly using encodings can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Directly converting your C++ code to JavaScript can be pretty straightforward just by adding the missing `.charCodeAt(0)` to the variable and to the string literals.

Also bear in mind that `'1' - '0'` in C++ is not the same as `'1' - '0'` in JavaScript, although the results are the same. The former subtracts a character code of `'0'` from a character code of `'1'`. The latter converts `'1'` to 1, `'0'` to 0, and calculates the difference. That's why you are receiving `NaN` with `c - 'a'`, where `'a'` (and probably `c`) is not convertible to a number.